# Why I am getting this error in osm?

Tags: javascript, dojo, leaflet, openstreetmap

I have started working on dojo and osm recently, so it might be a simple question but am not able to figure out why I am getting this error. the dojo code I have to load the map from osm is as below:

```
function InitMap() {
    map = L.map('map').setView([ 51.4848, -0.20325 ], 8);
    var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
    // 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';

    L
            .tileLayer(
                    osmUrl,
                    {
                        maxZoom : 18,
                        attribution : 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreet1Map</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery  <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>'
                    }).addTo(map);


    var popup = L.popup();

    function onMapClick(e) {
        popup.setLatLng(e.latlng).setContent(
                "You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString()).openOn(map);
    }
    map.on('click', onMapClick);
}
```

And the error I am getting in the browser console is: **ReferenceError: L is not defined** but the functionality wise there is no problem. 
Please let me know where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Is this code based on an example?

Comment: Did you include the leaflet.js?

Comment: there's a HUGE difference between **javascript** and **java**

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an OSM expert, but I think you are probably missing a script file.

Looking at the source for http://www.openstreetmap.org/  I see that the global variable `L` is  created as part of the first script (`/assets/application-67bdd93f2bbf379cc96f0e9af383c99c.js`)